# Created Element in function not appending to DOM

Tags: javascript, html

I am having some issues figuring out why my created Element won't append to the DOM within my function.

```js
let startText = document.querySelector('.text-container').innerHTML = "Lets Start.";
let lvlTitle = document.querySelector('.text-container');
let background = document.querySelector('.full-page');
lvlTitle.addEventListener('click', countChangeBackground);
var clicks = 0;

function countChangeBackground() {
  clicks += 1;
  var message = "";
  if (clicks == 1) {
    message = "Test";
    background.style.backgroundColor = "#f81884";
    lvlTitle.style.color = "#f2eee2";
  } else if (clicks == 2) {
    message = "Test2";
    background.style.backgroundColor = "#f5ce28";
    lvlTitle.style.color = "black";
  } else if (clicks == 3) {
    message = "Add Li to ul";

    var ul = document.querySelector('.text-container');
    var li = document.createElement('li');

    li.className = 'text-content';
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode('New Text'));
    ul.appendChild(li);
    console.log(li);
  } else {
    message = startText;
    background.style.backgroundColor = "#f2eee2";
    lvlTitle.style.color = "black";
  }
  lvlTitle.innerHTML = message;
};
```

```html
<div class="full-page">
  <div class="click-container">
    <ul class="text-container">
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is a jsfiddle:
[Append Li to DOM](http://jsfiddle.net/7jx194gp/1/)

Comment: Your `li` element is created and attached successfully, but then, on line 39, you set the `innerHTML` to be just the message text, which overwrites ALL html, including the newly added li.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the line causing you problems:

`lvlTitle.innerHTML = message;`

When you set the innerHTML, if there are other nodes inside of that element, they are overwritten.

You need to alter your logic to only set the innerHTML in some cases.

I've updated your jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/jepoqd01/

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the entire container with innerHTML and not reaching the correct content text

See solution add new variable lvlContainer with get the .text-container and lvlText get the .text-content

```
let startText = document.querySelector('.text-content').innerHTML = "Lets Start.";
let lvlTitle = document.querySelector('.text-content');
let lvlContainer = document.querySelector('.text-container');
let background = document.querySelector('.full-page');

lvlTitle.addEventListener('click', countChangeBackground);

var clicks = 0;

function countChangeBackground() {
  clicks += 1;
  var message = "";
  if (clicks == 1) {
    message = "Test";
    background.style.backgroundColor = "#f81884";
    lvlContainer.style.color = "#f2eee2";
  } else if (clicks == 2) {
    message = "Test2";
    background.style.backgroundColor = "#f5ce28";
    lvlContainer.style.color = "black";

  } else if (clicks == 3) {
    message = "Add Li to ul";

    var ul = document.querySelector('.text-container');
    var li = document.createElement('li');

    li.className = 'text-content';
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode('New Text'));
    ul.appendChild(li);
    console.log(li);
  } else {
    message = startText;
    background.style.backgroundColor = "#f2eee2";
    lvlContainer.style.color = "black";
  }
  lvlTitle.innerHTML = message;
};
```

is in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/lucaslimax/7jx194gp/37